# Properly typing useRef values in a React custom hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-ref

I have a custom hook that returns a value of `useRef` in my TS app. Unfortunately it is complaining about the type of the ref I am returning and I have no clue how to properly type this.

This is what my hook looks like:

```js
interface MyHookInterface {
    someBooleanState: boolean
    myRef: HTMLElement | null
}

  
const useMyHook = (): MyHookInterface => {
    const [someBooleanState, setSomeBooleanState] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const myRef = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null)
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const el = myRef.current // what type should this be?
      // Complaining that el possibly undefined 
      if(el?.offsetWidth < el?.scrollWidth){
          // do stuff
      }
    }, [])
  
    return {
        someBooleanState,
        myRef, // Getting: Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 234 more
    }
  }
```

As you can see in the comments, my hook has a few errors relating to typing:

1- Do not know how to type `myRef` in the interface. Keep in mind that it is to be used on multiple types of HTML elements, so I can not specify here whether it will be a div or what.

2- Do not know how to type `el`, but the access to its properties is complaining about it being `undefined`

How can I properly type these values in my hook?

Comment: In your interface, you are specifying the return type of `myRef` to be an HTMLELement, but in `useMyHook` you are return the Ref object. You should be returning `{ myRef: myRef.current }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 

This happens because a ref's value is stored under the ".current" property.

i.e.

```js
const Comp = () => {
...
    const refVal = React.useRef(2);
    console.log(2 === refVal); // false
    console.log(2 === refVal.current); // true
...
}
```

The solution depends on your intention - if you want to return the ref itself, change the type of the interface to `MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>` as suggested by the type error, otherwise, replace the return value with:

```js
    return {
        someBooleanState,
        myRef: myRef.current,
    }
```

2. 

You may be getting `undefined`s if el is not yet defined (i.e. if it hasn't been assigned yet) due to you accessing the property using the `?.` operator (which, to be clear, is correct.

e.g.

```
null?.test === undefined; // true
```

To solve this, check if el is defined and optionally (though this is not required by the interface's definition), check that both values are defined and are numbers (i.e. using `el && !isNaN(el?.offsetWidth) && !isNaN(el?.scrollWidth) && el.offsetWidth < el.scrollWidth`. Alternatively, use the nullish coalescing operator if this is applicable for your use case, i.e. `(el?.offsetWidth ?? 0) < (el?.scrollWidth ?? 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

The type of a ref is not just the object that it's referencing. It's a `React.MutableRefObject` that wraps what it's referencing. This is what provides the `current` property so the ref can work.

If you muse over `myRef` you should see the type you need.  In this case:

```
React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>
```

Which makes your hooks return type this:

```
interface MyHookInterface {
    someBooleanState: boolean
    myRef: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>
}
```

---

Secondly, the reason that this does not work:

```
  const el = myRef.current // what type should this be?
  
  // Complaining that el possibly undefined 
  if(el?.offsetWidth < el?.scrollWidth){
      // do stuff
  }
```

Is because your ref may not have been assigned a value yet. which means that `el?.offsetWidth` is `undefined`, because `el` is still `null`. And `undefined` is not a valid operand in a `<` comparison. (`if (undefined < undefined)` doesn't make much sense)

You can easily fix this by checking to make sure that `el` exists before you do the comparison:

```
  if (el && el.offsetWidth < el.scrollWidth){
      // do stuff
  }
```

[Working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=8&pln=17&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFLIBm1xAonXUhnAL5x1QQhwA5FFQZBAKHHAAdpSh10SOAFkAngAkIEANYBJWUnmLc4uGbiF+SAEJaANqmlkKSAFxwARvcenzIVfTuyOgwAHTK+OQeDvQA8h4AVuwwADzqACrKADJMDiBIsnAAPnDS+HZ2AHzinJJm4mgQ0oTwNGqaOnAAvHAAFACU7u1aegZGaEpdlSbmcI3N8ADalvm2EA4oTuSU2MQwJFZrG1suALrdBMTOlCle646VvQp2xP2+ZvMtcP70FzT0aUyOTyBXgJTKFUeELsb3qsxoLDYGF6A260xw73Mn3gSDsFx+SDooTQ+CgIkKAHoKXAAO4ACwocBgqjASkIdIg5QAJky6cBCJ4kAB+TFw2ZwKlwADC-DAdhQMhkAHNeYzcXBIIRCMBoqoCNIuYSZEgeaK4MA6L11QAya1wXGhCCsPYAdWAXJgdLgKXtdlChDQfAqbo9dP6GPF4slXIgFhg+FYZtqs042EWp1hcExInjUGkM0jFkO3k21yoZrMBIYEupAHEkDAYMr3OkWUpBBEojFCfEkhhAdlckh8oVweUqoJzQKQPztdIVZ6lHR1nYIDTlRq+KzYMAkALePwmW2hBlByDZIJ3OgJlqANJIVTYa97wj31RZFAeXFPyIQNAoMBgHIOxgAALyoOAuWAKAnwNOAACYAGYABZvmgJBMWTLhfCAA)

Comment: Relating to the `Object possibly undefined` warning, I thought the optional chaining operator (`?.`) would take care of that. No matter though, I could just do the check. Otherwise, all good!

Comment: As I've added in my answer above, the ?. operator is the reason for the warning, not a solution - it will indeed return undefined if el is null / undefined - i.e. `null?.test === undefined`.

Comment: @theJuls `?.` is a very handy operator convenience operator, but it doesn't always fit every case. In this case it does let you safely access a property on a maybe `null` object. However, it's not going to allow you to do math on `undefined`.